# Windows Taskbar - Prevent some applications from grouping?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, taskbar

This probably applies to either Vista or Windows 7...they both have a feature where it will group windows from the same app under a single button. However I have one application I want it to never group -- specifically an X11 server, where different windows are separate apps and not related (ie, I don't want it grouping my xterm window along with my accounting software window, just because they are both owned by xserver.exe).

I don't want to turn it completely off, I like when it groups all my Explorer windows together for example. I just want to exclude/whitelist/? a single application, xserver.exe, from having its windows grouped.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) should do exactly what you want:

> This programs enables you to tweak your Windows 7 taskbar. The tweaks
>   are divided into three sections:
>   **Taskbar items:** control taskbar items related stuff, like middle/right clicking, hovering, dropping, etc.
>   **Grouping and combining:** disable grouping, allow to drag windows between groups, force/disable combining, etc.
>   **Other taskbar options:** mouse wheel options, double/middle clicking on the empty space of the taskbar, and misc.

## Answer

To prevent only some applications from grouping in the Taskbar, using *Task Tweaker*, follow the instructions in the following screenshot. In this example, I am configuring it to prevent Outlook from grouping:

[image]

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but looks like it does exactly this. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! This program is a must for every Windows 7/8 user!!

Comment: Excuse me, but now does this do what the asker asked?  The requirement was to not group only _some_ applications.

Comment: It doesn't show in the screenshot, but there are per application-ID settings when you click on the Taskbar Inspector button.

Comment: This **does not help**!
7TT is a great application, but it can't define exceptions or specific rules for specific applications!

Comment: **`README:`** To alleviate the confusion in the comments, I edited this answer to add a better screenshot to show exactly how to use _7TT_ to prevent a single application from being grouped.