# How to change the taskbar grouping behavior for a single application in windows-7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Taskbar - Prevent some applications from grouping?](https://superuser.com/questions/44808/windows-taskbar-prevent-some-applications-from-grouping)

I love the new taskbar in windows-7 and how it groups and preview windows under a single big icon. Keeps things much more organized. However, sometimes it gets in my way.

I use visual studio a lot and from time to time I have two instances open. In those times I tend to switch between the two instances of Visual Studio and Firefox, not in any particular order. The thing is that now that the two VS windows are grouped together, I always have to use two clicks to get to one of them (click, white for animation, click again).

Is there any way I can windows-7 to group all windows except those who belong to a specific application (like visual studio)?

Thanks,
Boaz

PS. As some complimentary information: you can tell windows-7 to not group at all, or just do it when the task bar is full, by right-clicking on the taskbar, choose properties and change the taskbar buttons dropdown.

Comment: dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/44808/windows-taskbar-prevent-some-applications-from-grouping answer there: no known way currently.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone coming here via search, the duplicate Epaga linked to now has a solution.