# Grouping firefox (multitabs opened) buttom in taskbar(windows) as that of chrome

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, google-chrome, firefox, taskbar

To be fair i don't really know the jargon used to specify my question. let me describe it in this way.

Does Firefox (Firefox pin or button in task-bar that behaves as of the windows explorer pin) can be combined into a single pin or button like that of chrome though multiple tabs in the browsers are opened at the task-bar(windows)

Their behavior is as follows,

in chrome(using multiple tabs) if i click the button in the task-bar it opens directly to the previous tab that i minimized from .. whereas in Firefox it opens a multiple preview windows at the task-bar and i need to select the tab of my choice.

all i need is Firefox's button at task-bar to function as that of chrome . Is there a way to do so ?

NOTE : i'am aware of the link [Windows Taskbar - Prevent some applications from grouping?](https://superuser.com/questions/44808/windows-taskbar-prevent-some-applications-from-grouping) this tweaks just groups the pins and shows multiple preview windows to select . (i think chrome has updated to restore the tab last minimized from, when the button is just single clicked from task-bar)

Comment: Wow thats what iam searching for thank you.. :)

Comment: @Karan You should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Firefox Options > Tabs and uncheck *Show tab previews in the Windows taskbar*.